# Running a java "background application" in application server

Tags: java

My experience with application servers is limited to some basic servlet coding, so I am not even sure how to frame this question appropriately.

I need to write a java program that runs on the (java) application server and continuously executes a certain method (it will check for files in a certain directory).

I have found a way to schedule the start of applications but need to know where to put the code that I would normally put in the main() method in a regular java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), or the [EJB timer service](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Session5.html) (if you can learn EJBs) for this task.

If you have just a servlet container like Tomcat, it is preferable to go with Quartz. In fact, Quartz also comes with a [web application to monitor a scheduler](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/quartz/quartz-web-app.zip).

On the other hand, the EJB timer service is available in all EJB containers that support EJB 2.1 and above.

Answer (score 2):

Not answering straight to your question, but check out [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) that could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the servlet event listeners.

I think you should be able to hook into your code using a `ServletContextListener`.

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/04/12/listeners.html

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to write a Listener which implements ServletContextListener and you write you schedule your timer in contextInitialized method